# Where can I find my call history on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, log, nexus-4

This seems oddly missing on my nexus 4. I received a phone call the other day, and I forgot to add her as a contact. Now I am searching for that phone call, and I can't find a log readily accessible on my phone to find this. The only log is for messaging.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Go to the phone app, than pull up the window at the bottom, were it says Recent: lists All and Missed calls!

Comment: You probably need to use @konrad etc in comments to get peoples attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the phone app, than pull up the window at the bottom were it says Recent: lists All and Missed calls!